# How to fix rJava install error configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/bin/java' does not work

Tags: r, rjava

I am trying to install package "xlsx" in RStudio on a mac.  It tries to install rJava and I get the following error:

checking whether Java run-time works... No Java runtime present, requesting install.

> no configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/bin/java' does not work
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava’
>   * restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava’
>   Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘rJava’ had
>   non-zero exit status

It prompts me to go download Java and I do.  Once it is done installing I try to install package rJava again in RStudio and it give me the exact same error and prompts me to download Java again.

I can see Java in my system preferences but when I go to the terminal and type `java -version` I get the same prompt to go download Java.  It's like my computer just isn't recognizing Java.

Any idea for how I can fix this and get rJava installed?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/r-java-rjava-and-macos-adventures/ and here: http://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/ and my recent update here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056600/cant-load-rjava-on-macos-mojave-and-r-3-5-2/55070095#55070095

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue at linux... From "/usr/bin/java" you are using Linux, presume this is also the case. The required Java installer can be installed as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34165840/8939181) in linux terminal

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

by restarting R installation worked

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, and went to use openXLSX which doesn't require Java.